# Why is $\mathbb{G}_m$ is a representable functor?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, functors

What does it mean that multiplication $\mathbb{G}_m$ is a representable functor, with $\mathbb{G}_m = \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x,x^{-1}])$ ?

When I looked at the stacks project page on $\mathbb{G}_m$ they have for any scheme [[1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/022U)]

$$ \mathbb{G}_m : T \mapsto \Gamma (T, \mathcal{O}^*_T) $$

So I tested this definition on an scheme, $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q} = \text{Spec}( \mathbb{Q}[x])$ (the [affine line](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/affine+line) can be defined for any ring).  Then

$$ \mathbb{G}_m : \mathbb{Q} \mapsto \Gamma(\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{Q}^*) \simeq \mathbb{Q}^\times $$

The units of $\mathbb{Q}$ is everything but zero, $\mathbb{Q}^\times = \mathbb{Q} \backslash \{ 0 \}$.  This could work for now.

Next I looked up the definition of "[representable functor](http://courses.washington.edu/mnotes/alggroups/notes.pdf)".  We'd have that:

\begin{eqnarray*} \mathcal{F} &\simeq& \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}} (A, -) \\ \\
\mathbb{G}_m &\simeq& \text{Hom}_{k-\text{Alg}}(\text{Spec}[\mathbb{Z}[x, x^{-1}], -)
\end{eqnarray*}

I don't know a lot about affine group schemes, but I know I should definitely expect that $\mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}^\times$ and $\mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{Q}(i)) = \mathbb{Q}(i)^\times$.  I just wanted to see any clarification of how the category theory fits into here.

**Example** Here is a morphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}(i)\to \mathbb{Q}$ with $\phi:a + bi \mapsto a$.  What is $\mathbb{G}_m(\phi)$?  Certainly it is a  morphism of [groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism).

Comment: Is $\phi$ even a morphism in this category?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathbb{G}_m$ is a functor from the opposite of the category of schemes to the category of groups:
$$
\mathbb{G}_m : \mathsf{Sch}^{op}\to\mathsf{Grp}
$$
(or even to $\mathsf{Ab},$ as schemes are built from commutative rings). You can also define $\mathbb{G}_m$ as a functor on the category of commutative rings first via
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{G}_m : \mathsf{CRing}&\to\mathsf{Ab}\\
R&\mapsto R^\times.
\end{align*}
This extends to the original definition of $\mathbb{G}_m$ because affine schemes form a basis of the topology for schemes (and $\mathsf{Aff}\simeq\mathsf{CRing}^{op}$).

Now, $\mathbb{G}_m$ is not the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_{k\textrm{-}\mathsf{Alg}}(\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]),-);$ indeed, this does not even make sense! $\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}])$ is not an object in $k\textrm{-}\mathsf{Alg}$ - it's a scheme! The correct statement would be either
$$
\mathbb{G}_m\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sch}}(-,\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]))
$$
as functors $\mathsf{Sch}^{op}\to\mathsf{Grp},$ or
$$
\mathbb{G}_m\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{CRing}}(\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}],-)\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Aff}}(\operatorname{Spec}(-),\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]))
$$
as functors $\mathsf{CRing}\to\mathsf{Grp}.$ (So depending on which perspective you take, it is either representable or corepresentable. You might hear both abusively referred to as representable. Exercise: a representable functor is equivalent to the data of a [universal element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representable_functor#Universal_elements) - work out what that universal element is in this case!)

Once you know the contravariant correspondence between rings and affine schemes is given by $\operatorname{Spec},$ you can see why $\mathbb{G}_m(S) := \Gamma(S,\mathcal{O}_S)^\times$ is "the same" as $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{CRing}}(\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}],-).$ Indeed, it suffices to look at the situation when $S = \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is affine. In this case, $$\Gamma(R,\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(R)})^\times\cong R^\times.$$ On the other hand, a morphism of rings $$\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}]\to R$$ is given by choosing an invertible element of $R$ which $x$ maps to - so $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{CRing}}(\Bbb Z[x,x^{-1}],R)$ is naturally in bijection with $R^\times.$

You got the right answer for $\mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{A}^1_{\Bbb{Q}}),$ but let me make a few comments (some things you've written appear off). Since $\mathbb{A}^1_{\Bbb{Q}} = \operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Q[t])$ is affine, compute $\mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{A}^1_{\Bbb{Q}})$ as the units in $\Bbb Q[t]$ (or equivalently, units in $\Gamma(\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb Q},\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb Q}})$). This gives
$$
\mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{A}^1_{\Bbb{Q}}) = \mathbb{G}_m(\Bbb Q[t]) = \left(\Bbb Q[t]\right)^\times = \Bbb Q^\times,
$$
as the units of the polynomial ring over a field are simply the units of the field itself. What you've written appears to be the computation of $\Bbb G_m(\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Q) = \Bbb G_m(\Bbb Q) = \Bbb Q^\times.$ Perhaps you're thinking of $\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb Q}$ as being identified with $\Bbb Q,$ but this only accounts for some of the points in the scheme $\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb Q}.$ There are also points corresponding to [conjugacy classes of] Galois extensions of $\Bbb Q,$ and a generic point. When working over a non-algebraically closed field $k,$ one needs to be careful about identifying schemes $X/k$ with their $k$-rational points $X(k).$

To answer your last question, the map $\phi : \Bbb Q(i)\to\Bbb Q$ you've defined is not a morphism of rings - so it does not make sense to apply $\mathbb{G}_m$ to it. On the other hand, the inclusion $$\varphi : \Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q(i)$$ is a morphism of rings. Applying $\mathbb{G}_m$ gives the natural map $$\Bbb Q^\times\to\Bbb Q(i)^\times.$$

More generally, for any map of rings $R\to S,$ there is an induced group homomorphism on the groups of units $R^\times\to S^\times.$ This induced morphism is precisely the one you get when you apply $\mathbb{G}_m$ to the map $R\to S.$

A final remark: any scheme $X$ naturally defines a representable functor in the same way. That is, the scheme $X$ may be thought of as a functor
\begin{align*}
X : \mathsf{Sch}^{op}&\to\mathsf{Set}\\
S&\mapsto X(S) := \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sch}}(S,X).
\end{align*}
This is the so-called "[functor of points](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functorial+geometry)" perspective of scheme theory. An "$S$-valued point of $X$" is a morphism $S\to X.$ One can recover the set-theoretic points of the scheme $X$ by looking at morphisms from the spectra of various fields (which as topological spaces are simply points) to the scheme. The reason that $\mathbb{G}_m$ is a functor to the category of groups rather than sets is that it is naturally a [group object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_object) in $\mathsf{Sch},$ which gives the hom-sets $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\mathbb{G}_m)$ the structure of a group.

This is not unique to scheme theory - this may be done in any locally small category by the [Yoneda embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma#The_Yoneda_embedding) - but it is a particularly fruitful perspective here. This allows us to think of schemes as presheaves on the category $\mathsf{Sch},$ and in many of the typical [topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology) one considers on this category ([Zariski](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/020N), [etale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_topology), [fpqc](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03NV), [fppf](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/021L), see also [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Zariski+site), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_topology), and [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/topologies.pdf)), [the functors defined by schemes are in fact sheaves](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/scheme#as_sheaves_on_). Thinking about sheaves on the category of schemes (with respect to some topology) leads to the theory of [algebraic spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_space), [stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(mathematics)), and other exotic objects that arise in modern algebraic geometry.